# How to remove duplicates correctly using FOR loop

Tags: vba, excel

My question might seem too easy but unfortunately i am just a beginner in VBA.

I have a table with three columns where 1st contains company names (Column B), second- Directors' names (Column C), 3rd - Directors' IDs (column D) and the list of all companies (Column F). One company has a number of different directors so that in Column B a company name is repeated as many times as a number of directors in this company. Some companies can share the same director so that in Column C and D there are duplicates of names and IDs. However, according to the data some names are repeated several times within one company(kinda redundant information).

Here is an example of my table

[image]

So my target is to remove (delete) this redundant info, i.e. to remove Director duplicates for a particular company WHILE keeping those duplicates that are caused by the fact that several companies are sharing one or more directors. Technically I need to select the range of directors and their IDs corresponding to a certain company and then remove duplicates by IDs. And then repeat it for each company. Since I have 500 companies I would like to automate it somehow

here is the code i built in VBA (Remove duplicates function+for loop):

```
Sub test()

    Dim rcompany As Variant
    For X = 0 To 500
    rcompany = Range("F2").Offset(X, 0)

    Dim c As Range, r As Range


    For Each c In Range("B1:B23500")
        If c.Value = rcompany Then
            If r Is Nothing Then
                Set r = c.Offset
                      Else
                Set r = Union(r, c)
            End If
        End If

    Next c
    Union(r, r.Offset(, 1), r.Offset(, 2)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlNo

    Next
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that if I run it without a loop (for a particular company) it works well. But as soon as i add for loop it works well for 1st step but then it starts removing all duplicates within the whole Column D but not within a range according to a company name.

Could you please help me with it? how to improve it?

Comment: so if director names and company are the same for 2 rows then delete 1 of them? or am i over simplifying this?

Comment: and I am not quite sure how col F is diff from col B? is col B 1 company and col F all of the companies that he is a director for?

Comment: Regarding the deletion it s unfortunately a bit different from what you understood. It is like that: for example, there is a company BlueWings and it has 3 directors John with ID 1(repeated twice), Mark with ID 2 (three times) and Jack with ID 3(once). Overall there will be 2+3+1=6 rows in column C and D for this company so that the BlueWings is repeted 6 times in Column B respectively.

Comment: What i need to do is to remove duplicates in Column C and D for Jack and Mark for BlueWings ONLY rather than removing duplicates in the whole Column C and D cause these people might repeat for other companies.

Comment: Regarding column F it is different from column B in the way that it contains unique names only, i.e. list where the names are following each other without any repetition. Whereas in Column B as i commented earlier contains repeated names of companies.

Comment: Show example data of your sheet, please, to speed up finding solution.

Comment: I d love to but i cannot upload pictures here and i don't know how to insert a table. Every time i copy and paste here it turns out to be a long string. If you could assist i d appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried adding a column with a key composed of two fields concatenated, then sort by that column? So you can just scroll through that column and delete each line `n+1` when its value is the same as `n`

Comment: stenci, I believe this solution is really helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3057799: Just post the picture as a link and somebody will include it! :-) Regarding your issue: I don't see why you cannot simply copy the full table and then apply the "Remove duplicates" functionality (checking all columns)?!?

Comment: oh! Thx) It's really helpful to communicate on this site. I should have opened it for myself before) Regarding your solution it leads to the deletion of all the duplicates in column C and D rather than  with respect to a particular company. However, having the column proposed by stenci this functionality turned out to be very efficient. Many thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

If a solution is to create a new column of unique values, I just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337742/name-manager-in-excel/20344038#20344038

The gist of it:

Suppose your list of names (containing duplicates) is in column A, and your list of unique values is in column B (B1 is the title).

B2 is equal A2. B3 and onward uses this formula:

```
  =INDEX(A$2:A$20,MATCH(TRUE,ISNA(MATCH(A$2:A$20,B$2:B2,0)),0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate. But it is not exactly what i need cause it will indicate unique values for the whole range of names within all companies. I need unique values of names for a particular company but not for all of them.